# Can't open Nvidia X Server settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xserver

This was asked before, but it wasn't answered, so I'm not sure what to do here, After switching to Intel to save battery power in the Nvidia X server settings I couldn't open it any more when I click it just does nothing.

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Or maybe it was because I installed Nvidia driver 396. If so, I don't know how to uninstall it, purging Nvidia didn't remove it at all.

```
$ inxi-MG
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 7559 v: 1.2.8 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Dell model: 0H0CC0 v: A00 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Dell v: 1.2.8 date: 05/14/2018
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 530
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: nvidia
           Resolution: 960x540@59.82hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5
```

Comment: How did you install the driver?  Normally to remove the 396 driver it is just `sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-396` in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: After doing so, ubuntu still says I have it installed with the `ubuntu-drivers list` command, which displays both nvidia-driver-390 and nvidia-driver-396. The x server settings still don't open.

Comment: I removed a ppa from the software & updates program, and it did remove the nvidia-driver-396, though nvidia x settings still won't open, so I assume it's because I switched to Intel, is there another way to switch back to Nvidia without using the settings panel?

Comment: Could you run `inxi -MG` and paste the output to your question?  That should show the motherboard and graphics card(s) in the system.

Comment: I've updated and pasted what it displayed after typing the command.
The resolution is supposed to be 1080p.

Comment: I'm upvoting your question here to hopefully give it more views.  This is beyond what I could do since I do not own a system with dual video in a system so I could not write you a good answer that I have tested.  Sorry about that.  I was helping getting more information into your question that could help others answer it.

Comment: That's alright, thanks for the help any way, I'll keep on looking to see if I can fix my problem

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem. I resolved it by running the command

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and rebooting.

After reboot I was able to open nvidia X server settings.

Comment: This worked for me. Glad I didn't have to spend hours reinstalling Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only or easiest way to fix this problem is to just reinstall Ubuntu, I managed to get Nvidia settings to open with the Intel as the selected graphics driver by purging Nvidia and installing Nvidia settings before installing the driver, but it's missing the settings Nvidia I supposed to have.
So from what I got here, if you have nvidia and Intel hd graphics in the same computer, probably don't switch to Intel for power saving (after having nvidia installed of course), it just broke my installation.
If anyone could get a better solution to this feel free to do so, I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: With more information, I've gathered after reinstalling Linux it's still causing problems and with further research - I'm not completely sure on this - but apparently, it has something to do with the Nvidia driver not being able to connect to the monitor properly at all, no matter how many times I reinstall Ubuntu or change the way I install it, it won't work, If I still can't find a solution to this I'll probably open a new question instead of adding to this one.